# generating all permutations with all orderings and replacements in Python

Tags: python

How to generate all possible ordering of a set of elements in a list which:

1. generates all ordering (not only those with sorted order)
2. allows repetition

I know that using `itertools.permutations(iterable[, r])` I can do the following:

```
import itertools

a = itertools.permutations([1,2])
list(a)
```

output:

```
[(1, 2), (2, 1)]
```

and also using the `itertools.combinations_with_replacement(iterable, r)`:

```
import itertools

a = itertools.combinations_with_replacement([1,2],2)
list(a)
```

output:

```
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2)]
```

but what I want is a `function` which does the following:

```
a = function([1,2],2)
```

output:

```
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
```

In other words, for a list of size n with distinct elements and a given input of r it could generate all possible n**r possible combinations

Answer (score 3):

`itertools.product([1,2],repeat=2)`

I think...

Comment: Yes, that worked! thanks!